# Busca com group by

Tags: sql, group-by, order-by

Suponha a seguinte tabela que registra os posts de autores em um blog.

Um autor pode ter varios posts.

Então tenho várias repetições de autores nessa tabela dos diferentes posts que ele fez.

Como devo fazer uma consulta para buscar o conteúdo do post mais recente de acordo com a coluna data_post.

Por exemplo, do autor de id_autor = 1 o post mais recente dele é do dia 25-08-2018 com o conteúdo ciencias.

Fiz a seguinte busca mas está me retornando o conteúdo politica ao invés de ciências:

Todos os resultados:[image: IMAGEM]

Resultado com group by: [image: IMAGEM]
Consulta:

```
SELECT id_post,id_autor,MAX(data_post),conteudo_post FROM teste group by id_autor order by data_post DESC;
```

Se quiserem replicar o exemplo segue o create e joguei no jsfidle o json caso queiram importar os dados.
https://jsfiddle.net/0ofe976w/1/

```
CREATE TABLE `teste` (
`id_post` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_autor` int(11) NOT NULL,
`data_post` date DEFAULT NULL,
`conteudo_post` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_post`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, não estava funcionando por conta de que não é possível juntar uma coluna agregada (no casa a data máxima) com dados não agrupados.

Primeiro, vamos chamar a tabela principal de `T`. Depois, a partir da `subquery`, é feito um `SELECT`, retornando a data máxima e o id do autor correspondente, chamando ela de `D`.

**Tabela D**

```
 id_autor | MAX_DATA
-------------------------
     1    | 25/08/2018
     2    | 25/08/2018
     3    | 25/07/2018
     4    | 27/09/2018
```

Com essa nova tabela que foi retornada, é feito um `SELECT` com `INNER JOIN`, puxando os campos onde o id do autor e a data da `tabela D` é igual ao id do autor e a data da `tabela T`:

```
SELECT T.id_post, T.id_autor, D.MAX_DATA, T.conteudo_post
FROM (
    SELECT id_autor, MAX(data_post) AS MAX_DATA
    FROM teste
    GROUP BY id_autor
) AS D
INNER JOIN teste AS T
ON T.id_autor = D.id_autor AND T.data_post = D.MAX_DATA;
```

**Motivo do Não Funcionamento**

O `SELECT` simples, simplesmente mostra o primeiro dado da coluna não agregada, por exemplo:

`SELECT id_autor, MAX(data_post) AS MAX_DATA, conteudo_post FROM teste GROUP BY id_autor;`

Essa `query` retorna a seguinte ordem:

```
| conteudo_autor 
  --------------
|  politica    
|  politica    
|  tecnologia  
|  economia
```

Que como você pode analisar, a imagem que foi colocada na pergunta, cada conteúdo retornado é respectivamente o primeiro conteúdo de cada autor.

Comment: Perfeito...entendi...acho engraçado o MySQL deixar selecionar colunas que não estão com uma função agregada tipo o MAX ou não estão no group by. Que tipo de função ele usa para escolher qual dado exibir que não esta agregado no group by ou que não está contido numa função de agregação?
Por exemplo essa consulta:
SELECT id_autor, MAX(data_post) AS MAX_DATA,conteudo_post
    FROM teste
    GROUP BY id_autor
A coluna conteudo_post não está com uma função de agregação e não está no group by, como ele decide qual linha mostrar?